# Differential heights for two adjacent CSS rows either in flex box or css grid

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, css-grid

The problem is I have two columns that will be filled with rows that are implicitly defined, and that I DO NOT want to resize the adjacent row items such that there is a space beside the components. I have tried using grid, but the result is the second image. Similarly, I use flexbox, and the row space emerges implicitly. Does anyone know a way to get this kind of 'dense' packing as in the first image?

[image: what I'd like]

[image: What I have]

Comment: You want to spread out the boxes evenly vertically?  Flex should do that.  Make each column a flex container with `display: flex`, set `flex-direction` to `column`, and set `justify-content` to `space-between`.

Comment: @dmikester1 it's more that when the menu is expanded, the adjacent row item should not automatically create space below it, but you may be correct in this approach. Thanks for the input.